# how to remove [+£xxx] weight adjustment from product attributes on product detail page in nopcommerce 3.8

Tags: nopcommerce-3.80

I want to remove the [+£xxx] weight adjustment from product attributes on product detail page in nopcommerce 3.8.

For more clear let see the image

[image]

the red box indicates the weight adjustment of product attribute which I want to remove.

Is there any admin setting or done by code.

If code then where I want to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. By removing [{1}] value from products.productattributes.priceadjustment resource name in language.